SharePoint Default Content Type deleted - restore
I have an issue and I hope to find a solution. We have SharePoint Online. When cleaning up some old content types in the SharePoint administration a major error happened.
I deleted some old document sets. When doing so I didn't spend enough attention and really messed it up. I have not only deleted the custom content types, which are not needed anymore, but also a default content type.
I deleted the "document set" content type in the SharePoint admin (and therefore also in the content typ hub). Directly after doing so I realized what I have done and tried to find a way to restore it. Unfortunately, I have not found any results online - nor I was able to figure out something on my own.
Can anybody help?
Thanks!

What happens when you disable and enable the document set feature on the admin center site?

Restoring a deleted content type directly in the SharePoint Admin Content Type Gallery is not possible. However, you can try to recreate the "document set" content type and see if this affects the existing document set.
Create or customize a content type

Thanks for the idea.
